# Why is my no-cors fetch() not ok even if the request succeed?

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete Javascript beginner. I'm trying to poll a JSON for a status page with this code :

```js
setInterval(refresh, 5000);
var beat_state = 0;

function refresh()
{
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/", {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}, mode: 'no-cors'}).then(
        function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                document.getElementById("hearth").textContent = "❤️";
                response.json().then(update_display);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("hearth").textContent = "️";
            }
        }
    );
}
function update_display(json_health)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The server return this response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 186
Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2020 20:25:59 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.55

{"socket_listening": true,"quick_shutdown": false,"workers_online": 20,"workers_sleeping": 19,"workers_backlog": 0,"connections": [{"id": 4,"active_requests": 1,"socket_insane": false}]}
```

I'm doing test with a standalone on-disk HTML page.
Given that the Firefox 80.0.1 console show that the request is successful with no error. Why is `reponse.ok` false ?

Comment: can you `console.log(response)` to see if it contains an `ok` status key ?

Comment: Yes, here's the result : `Response { type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, body: null, bodyUsed: false }
preview.html:24:15`

Comment: Status is 0, that shouldn't be.

Comment: as you can see `ok` is false inside the response, that is why the else case is being excetued

Comment: Yes. But my question is why this `ok` is false if the request succeed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you have mode:'no-cors'

you will get a response with type: "opaque"

which returns status:0

and since ok is only true on status in the range 200-299 you get ok:false

sources:

[OK status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok)

[what type opaque does](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque)

[opaque being response for no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the fetch syntax, it seems that you've done some nested ".then"s, that may cause the fetch not to work
In order to have the process run and catch errors, maybe something like this will work

```
setInterval(refresh, 5000);
var beat_state = 0;


function refresh()
{
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/", {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}, mode: 'no-cors'})
        .then(function(response) { if (response.ok) {
                document.getElementById("hearth").textContent = "❤️";
                return response.json();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("hearth").textContent = "️";
            }
 })
       .then(function(json) {
       update_display();
}
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error.message);
})
```